# Python | Openpyxl | Read the Images present in the excel sheets

Tags: python-3.x, excel, python-requests, openpyxl

I have an excel file with images (either png, jpeg or .emf) format.

**Concerns:**

1. Openpyxl not able to find the images in .emf format.
2. Openpyxl is able to detect images that are in png and jpeg. But how do I read the image content? Because I want to read the image in 'rb' mode and send it as attachment via a post request.

Excel Snapshot:
[image]

My code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
path = "path to the excel file"
wb = load_workbook(path)
# active sheet that contains the image
sh = wb.active

# get the images info
sh._images
>>>[<openpyxl.drawing.image.Image object at 0x000002516ADBDD00>]

# need code to read this image in 'rb' format.

# Code to make post request
import requests
url = "api_endpoint_url"
files = {'File-Name': ('image1.png', <image read in rb mode here>, 'image/png')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Thanks for the help. Please let me know if you need any information.

Comment: Don't know if this is possible with Openpyxl. Xlwings will get all images even the .emf however not sure about extracting the images. Another option that you could consider is to unzip the xlsx and just obtain the original image files. Should be in ...\xl\media I think.

Comment: @moken Thank you for the reply. Yeah I am trying the unzip option as a last resort.

Comment: Charlie Clark hasn't commented on Openpyxl ability to support doing this so if you haven't already you might want to try raising with them directly; https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. And if you can/want to try xlwings you can raise with them on github.